# Generated SwaggerUI from OpenAPI definition doesn't show all information

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

In a Spring Boot **3** application I want to throw in easily some OpenAPI definition files (*.yaml) so the SwaggerUI is generated automatically via the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
   <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>6.4.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
          <goals>
             <goal>generate</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
             <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/openApi.yaml</inputSpec>
             <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
             <apiPackage>org.company.api.v1</apiPackage>
             <modelPackage>org.company.model.v1</modelPackage>               
             <supportingFilesToGenerate>ApiUtil.java</supportingFilesToGenerate>
             <configOptions>
                 <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                 <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                 <useTags>true</useTags>
             </configOptions>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The issue is that the generated SwaggerUI doesn't care about the `info` section within the OpenAPI defintion:

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: Swagger Table
  description: Whatever it takes, stay strong
  license:
    name: MIT
servers:
  -
    url: '/api/v1'
paths:
  /table:
```

However in the end the SwaggerUI looks as follows:

[image]

Any idea how to configure the `open-api-generator-maven-plugin` in such a way that OpenAPI definition is regarded completely? I cannot find any properties ([plugin](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin) and [Spring generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring)) for this.

By the way, for the SwaggerUI itself the `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` dependency in version 2.0.2 is used as well.

---

In the meantime, I have figured out that the following missing code is the reason. So how can I let it generate without doing it by hand and instead by the `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`?

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "org.company.configuration.DispoConfiguration.apiInfo")
    OpenAPI apiInfo() {
        return new OpenAPI()
                .info(
                        new Info()
                                .title("OpenApi Definition for my zuege")
                                .description("Here comes the description!!!")
                                .license(
                                        new License()
                                                .name("MIT")
                                                .url("http://unlicense.org")
                                )
                                .version("1.0.0")
                )
                ;
    }

}
```

The subsequent screenshot shows my IDE in which the generated `configPackage` on the left side, actually intended for the generated *@Configuration* class, is empty:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try your yaml file like this:

```yaml
---
swagger: "2.0"
info:
  description: "This is a sample server Petstore server."
  version: "1.0.0"
  title: "Swagger Petstore"
  termsOfService: "https://swagger.io/terms/"
  contact:
    email: "apiteam@swagger.io"
  license:
    name: "Apache 2.0"
    url: "https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html"
```

Comment: This doesn't help; source code generation fails completely now. Your changes only differ in `swagger: 2.0` from what I have but now it is worse.

Comment: How does your entire yaml looks like?

Comment: above in the description I have added the complete beginning of the OpenAPI Definition (YAML file) but it is very long so the rest is skipped. But to make it clear when I paste it e.g. into editor.swagger.io there are no errors so it is a valid OpenAPI Definition.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, so I just put your class "MyConfiguration" in my non-generated code and it works. Thanks for the workaround.